# How can I restrict the dates available in an <Input type='date'> element?

Tags: php, html, input

I want to create a form with a date input but user can't choose all date:
For example, if an user fills in the form on Monday 24 May (day 0), he can choose one:

```
Friday 28 May (day 4)
Saturday 29 May (day 5)
Friday 3 July (day 11)
Saturday 4 July (day 12)
Friday 10 July (day 18)
Saturday 11 July (day 19)
```

but if he fills it in at Thursday 27 May (day 0), he can choose one:

```
Friday 28 May (day 1)
Saturday 29 May (day 2)
Friday 3 July (day 8)
Saturday 4 July (day 9)
Friday 10 July (day 15)
Saturday 11 July (day 15)
```

In all case user can choose Friday and Saturday of this week, the next and the other next.

I really don't know if it's possible or if I need to use a select, and if so then how?

Answer (score 0):

> "In all case user can choose Friday and Saturday of this week, the next and the other next."

***This can be achieved using the datepicker itself.***

```
$("#dp").datepicker({
  beforeShowDay: function(date){ return [date.getDay() == 5 || date.getDay() == 6,""]},
  minDate: 0,
  maxDate: "+3w"
});
```

Working JSFiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/sanjeevsarkar/zyve78wu/8/

**OR In case you want custom dates:**

You can use jQuery Datepicker `beforeShowDay` and pass the available dates while loading the page with PHP.

```
var available_formatted_dates_list = ['28-05-2021','29-05-2021', '04-06-2021', '05-06-2021', '11-06-2021', '12-06-2021'];

$(function() {
  $("input[id$=DateText]").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
    beforeShowDay: check_available_date
  });
});

function check_available_date(date) {
  var formatted_date = '',
    ret = [true, "", ""];
  if (date instanceof Date) {
    formatted_date = $.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', date);
  } else { formatted_date = '' + date; }
  if (-1 === available_formatted_dates_list.indexOf(formatted_date)) {
    ret[0] = false;
    ret[1] = "date-disabled";
    ret[2] = "Date not available";
  }
  return ret;
}
```

Here is a JSFiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/sanjeevsarkar/t8namfq1/2/

**NOTE:**

> Where there is a problem, there must be a solution.

Please note that once the user posts the form, if possible do a ***backend validation too*** for the dates, as *the UI form data can be manipulated from the browser*.

Comment: This assumes the original poster is using/wants a jQuery solution.  The tags on the question indicate otherwise.

Answer (score -1):

```
$today = date('Y-m-d');
  $todayDay =  date("l");
  if($todayDay == 'Monday'){
    $jour1 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($today. ' + 4 days'));
    $jour2 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($today. ' + 5 days'));
    $jour3 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($today. ' + 11 days'));
    $jour4 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($today. ' + 12 days'));
    $jour5 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($today. ' + 18 days'));
    $jour6 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($today. ' + 19 days'));
  }
  if($todayDay == 'Tuesday'){
    $jour1 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($today. ' + 3 days'));
    $jour2 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($today. ' + 4 days'));
    $jour3 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($today. ' + 10 days'));
    $jour4 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($today. ' + 11 days'));
    $jour5 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($today. ' + 17 days'));
    $jour6 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($today. ' + 18 days'));
  }
```

i make this, it's not beautiful but it's work